# RavenDB paging index

Tags: linq, pagination, ravendb

I have a Linq query as

```
var mdls = (from mdl in query dbSession.Query<MyModel>("MyIndex")
              orderby mdl.Name
              select dept).Skip(page.Value).Take(4);
```

Where "MyIndex" is a simple index defined in RavenDB. I know that while querying an Index in RavenDB it returns "TotalResults". See [here](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-http-indexes-querying)

How can i get the query result which has the `TotalResult` property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are executing a LuceneQuery you get a DocumentQuery returned that has a QueryResult property that contains TotalResults so you can access it as follows:

```
var documentQuery = (from mdl in query dbSession.LuceneQuery<MyModel>("MyIndex")
                     orderby mdl.Name
                     select dept).Skip(page.Value).Take(4);

var totalResults = documentQuery.QueryResult.TotalResults;
```

If you're executing a LINQ Query instead then you can call Count() on the query before limiting it with Skip and Take:

```
var linqQuery = (from mdl in query dbSession.Query<MyModel>("MyIndex")
                      orderby mdl.Name
                      select dept);

var totalResults = linqQuery.Count();

var pageOfResults = linqQuery.Skip(page.Value).Take(4);
```

Comment: I get `QueryResult` if i do `LuceneQuery<Department>` but not in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this at the end of your query

```
.Customize(x => x.TotalResult)
```

The TotalResult property is only available on the LuceneQuery, not the LINQ Query.

Comment: I didn't find `x.TotalResult` property. can you please show me the complete LINQ statement.

Comment: Sorry I missed a bit out, see the docs for the full syntax, http://ravendb.net/faq/total-results-in-paged-data-set

Comment: there it talks about `session.LuceneQuery<T>` but here I am using `session.Query<T>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can get `QueryResult` through `session.LuceneQuery<YouModel>("YourIndex")` and not from `session.Query<YourModel>("YourIndex")`. But, I wonder why would one use `session.Query<YourModel>("YourIndex")` ?